# Rectangles overlapping while attempting to enlarge the GUI of a maze

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, maze

My adventure with the maze and GUI continues, and at the moment I can see any graph `G=(V,E)`
where the Vertices are rooms, and the Edges are connectors (Doors or Walls), but the dimensions of the rectangles are too small so I've attempted to enlarge them but the rectangles step one over one another.

Given the following code :

```
private void drawMaze(PaintEvent e) {
  Graph maze = new Graph();
  maze.generateMaze(25);

  int i = 0;
  int level = 25;

  e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
  e.gc.setBackground(new Color(e.display, 150, 150, 150));
  e.gc.setLineWidth(12);

  e.gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));

  while (i < level) {
    Connector connector = maze.getEdgeConnectorByIndex(i);
    if (connector instanceof Door) {

      e.gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));

      Room room1 = ((Door)connector).getFirstRoom();
      Room room2 = ((Door)connector).getSecondRoom();
      int x = room1.getXcoordinate()+10;
      int y = room1.getYcoordinate()+10;

      int x1 = room2.getXcoordinate()+10;
      int y1 = room2.getYcoordinate()+10;

      e.gc.fillRectangle(x*30,y*30,20,20);  
      e.gc.fillRectangle(x1*30,y1*30,20,20); 
      e.gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));

      Room r1 = new Room(30*x,30*y);
      Room r2 = new Room(30*x1,30*y1);
      Coordinate c = this.checkWhereConnectorLocated(r1,r2);
      if (c.getSign() == DIAGONAL)
        e.gc.fillRectangle(c.getXCoordinate(),c.getYCoordinate(),10,20);
      else
        e.gc.fillRectangle(c.getXCoordinate(),c.getYCoordinate(),20,10);

    }



    if (connector instanceof Wall) {
      e.gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));

      Room room1 = ((Wall)connector).getFirstRoom();
      Room room2 = ((Wall)connector).getSecondRoom();
      int x = room1.getXcoordinate()+10;
      int y = room1.getYcoordinate()+10;

      int x1 = room2.getXcoordinate()+10;
      int y1 = room2.getYcoordinate()+10;

      e.gc.fillRectangle(x*30,y*30,20,20);
      e.gc.fillRectangle(x1*30,y1*30,20,20);  
      e.gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_RED));

      Room r1 = new Room(30*x,30*y);
      Room r2 = new Room(30*x1,30*y1);
      Coordinate c = this.checkWhereConnectorLocated(r1,r2);

      if (c.getSign() == DIAGONAL)
        e.gc.fillRectangle(c.getXCoordinate(),c.getYCoordinate(),10,20);
      else
        e.gc.fillRectangle(c.getXCoordinate(),c.getYCoordinate(),20,10);
    }

    i++;
  }

}

//  void org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.fillRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int
//  height)


private Coordinate checkWhereConnectorLocated(Room room1,Room room2) {

  int x = 0; int y = 0;
  Coordinate coordinate ;

  if (room1.getXcoordinate() == room2.getXcoordinate()) {
    // same X coordinate
    if (room1.getYcoordinate() > room2.getYcoordinate()) {
      // ROOM1 is located above ROOM2 - same X different Y 

      x = room1.getXcoordinate();
      y = room1.getYcoordinate()-10;
      coordinate = new Coordinate(x,y);
    }
    else {
      // ROOM2 is located above ROOM1 
      x = room1.getXcoordinate();
      y = room2.getYcoordinate()-10;
      coordinate = new Coordinate(x,y);

    }

    coordinate.setSign(HORIZONTAL);
    return coordinate;
  }

  else if (room1.getYcoordinate() == room2.getYcoordinate()) {
    // else maybe same Y coordinate  - the X is changing 
    if (room1.getXcoordinate() > room2.getXcoordinate()) {
      // ROOM1 is on the right of ROOM2 l
      x = room1.getXcoordinate() - 10;
      y = room2.getYcoordinate();          // same Y so there is no difference
                                           // whom Y's we choose
      coordinate = new Coordinate(x,y);
    }

    else {
      // ROOM2 is on the right of ROOM1
      x = room2.getXcoordinate() - 10;
      y = room2.getYcoordinate();          // same Y so there is no difference
                                           // whom Y's we choose
      coordinate = new Coordinate(x,y);
    }

    coordinate.setSign(DIAGONAL);
    return coordinate;
  }

  coordinate = new Coordinate(0,0);
  return coordinate;

}
```

The output:

[image]

The green rectangles are the `rooms` and the `red` and `blue` are the `connectors`. As you can see, the rectangles are too small and I need a size something like "60". However, I can't seem to find the correct combination of values for `fillRectangle` and `x,x1,y,y1`, where the rectangles won't be one over the other.

Can someone please explain how I can fix this?

Comment: is that you homework we are trying to help you solve..? ;]

Comment: This is my homework indeed , but I did not ask you to solve them.As you can see here ,I posted the code that I've been working on for the last few days , and I've worked very hard on that code ,however I asked you to help me diagnose what's wrong with it , NOT to solve it,so I'd appreciate your help with that .

Comment: It did not have offensive meaning ;], as a teacher (I also teach on University), I'm glad that you're working on that problem and trying to solve it even if there are some parts which seems hard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the data, so I'm not totally sure, that my approach will correctly rendeder the result you want, but I did simplified your code and add some constants for you for free change of basic sizes.

```
private final int boxSize = 60;
private final int connectorSize = 20;
private final int topOffset = 50;
private final int leftOffset = 50;
private Color roomColor = null;
private Color wallColor = null;
private Color doorColor = null;

private void drawMaze(PaintEvent e) {
    GC gc = e.gc;
    int i = 0;
    int level = 25;
    Graph maze = new Graph();

    maze.generateMaze(level);

    gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
    gc.setBackground(new Color(e.display, 150, 150, 150));

    while (i < level) {
        Connector connector = maze.getEdgeConnectorByIndex(i);

        gc.setBackground(roomColor);

        Room room1 = connector.getFirstRoom();
        Room room2 = connector.getSecondRoom();

        // left top corner X of room is offset from left side + coordinate mul size of box plus number of connectors between boxes already drawn before current room mul connector size
        int roomX = leftOffset + room1.getXcoordinate() * boxSize + (room1.getXcoordinate() - 1) * connectorSize;
        // left top corner Y of room is offset from top + coordinate mul size of box plus number of connectors between boxes already drawn above current room mul connector size
        int roomY = topOffset + room1.getYcoordinate() * boxSize + (room1.getYcoordinate() - 1) * connectorSize;

        gc.fillRectangle(roomX, roomY, boxSize, boxSize);

        if (connector instanceof Door) gc.setBackground(doorColor);
        if (connector instanceof Wall) gc.setBackground(wallColor);

        int connectorX = 0;
        int connectorY = 0;
        int connectorWidth = 0;
        int connectorHeight = 0;

        // room have same X, second is above or under the first
        if (room1.getXcoordinate() == room2.getXcoordinate()) {
            connectorWidth = boxSize;
            connectorHeight = connectorSize;
            connectorX = roomX;
            // check if it's under
            if (room1.getYcoordinate() > room2.getYcoordinate()) connectorY = roomY - connectorSize;
            else connectorY = roomY + boxSize;
        }
        // room have same Y, second is on right or left side of the first
        else {
            connectorWidth = connectorSize;
            connectorHeight = boxSize;
            connectorY = roomY;
            // check if it's right side
            if (room1.getXcoordinate() > room2.getXcoordinate()) connectorX = roomX - connectorSize;
            else connectorX = roomX + boxSize;
        }

        gc.fillRectangle(connectorX, connectorY, connectorWidth, connectorHeight);

        // draw the second room
        gc.setBackground(roomColor);

        roomX = leftOffset + room2.getXcoordinate() * boxSize + (room2.getXcoordinate() - 1) * connectorSize;
        roomY = topOffset + room2.getYcoordinate() * boxSize + (room2.getYcoordinate() - 1) * connectorSize;

        gc.fillRectangle(roomX, roomY, boxSize, boxSize);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Replace `Ancestor` with the correct class. (If you don't have some common ancestor class, or those methods are not in `Connector` class, make them! ;])

**EDIT**

I've made correction of based on your actual code, so check the new version.

You have also mistake in level generation, the loop have to finished at `>=1`, you have only `>1` so one room is missing, that's why NullPointerException was thrown up on my first version of code.

Also this code goes straight at the beginning of `BasicShapes` class constructor

```
roomColor = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN);
wallColor = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
doorColor = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
```

Comment: The code compile ,but the program crash in run time . I prefer not to post the Graph class since it includes my algorithm for building the maze (something like PRIM algorithm) . Can I send you the code in PM ?

Comment: It violates the rules of StackOverflow little bit.Did you see my edits? I realized that it might throw ClassCastException but I solve that.. If it won't work (even the edit version), please post the error message.

Comment: I have a long night in front of me ,I will into the changes you've made.Thank you very much for the help! Ron.

Comment: You're welcome, I have fingers crossed.. If you'll get to trouble, stackoverflow users will help you ;]..